# Vb.net FTP - get timestamp value?

Tags: vb.net, string, ftp, timestamp

I'm getting the timestamp value of an ftp file like this:

```
ftpRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp
```

Through:

```
ftpResponse.StatusDescription
```

It returns:

> 213 20120512102159

I'm pretty sure 213 is the ftp status code, and then 20120512102159 would be 2012, 05(may), 12(12th), then probably HH MM SS... But this doesn't match my local system, so possibly the FTP server's local time?

Anyhow... This value is a string, am I missing some obvious value of just the date? Otherwise, how do I get this string as a datetime value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this to parse the string out:

```
Dim dateValue as DateTime
dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(ftpResponse.StatusDescription.substring(4, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                            DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: There's some ')' missing, could you please adjust your code snippet accordingly?